# SonarLint saying socket is not closed even closed

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have the following piece of code. SonarLint saying socket should be closed in finally block.

But I have already closed it.
I have observed one more thing here is: I am getting this only if I have serverSocket.isClosed() condition in finally if condition. If I remove it, the issue is solved.

Here I wanna know that what is the problem with this condition becoz of that sonarLint could not recognize the socket closing.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try
{
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if(serverSocket != null && !serverSocket.isClosed())
    {
        try
        {
           serverSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the this : `if(serverSocket != null &&`

You are using an `if` statement and checking if the serverSocket in **NOT NULL AND**
here the problem is that is `serverSocket` is not null then the `&&` operator will not let the next condition to execute and the `if` statement will not execute,eventually, the connection will not closed.

Comment: thanks for responding.But it seems you have not read my question properly.What I am saying is, yea it is closing but if have extra condition(serverSocket.isClosed())  in finally block, Due to this sonarLint saying socket is not closed.Why?

Comment: @SravaniYapamanu It's not the `isClosed()` test (which is redundant anyway). It's the lack of this nested `finally` block in your code.

Comment: Updated my answer